# Borel-Cantelli Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas

The following is a problem from Stei-Shakarchi's Real Analysis:

Suppose $(E_n)$ be a countable family of measurable sets such that $\sum_n m(E_n)<\infty$. Define $E=\{ x\in\mathbb{R}^d\colon x\in E_k \mbox {for infinitely many } k\}$. The problem is to show that $E$ is measurable. The hint given is 
**write $E=\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} \cup_{k\geq n} E_k$**.

I could not understand the Hint. I mean, from given definition of $E$, I couldn't come to the interpretation in hint. Can you help me?

Comment: Extra hint:  Use continuity of the measure.

Comment: Oh sorry, you just want to show measurability?  That's not normally the Borel-Cantelli Theorem, the conclusion is usually to show that $m(E)=0$.  Just recall your definition of a $\sigma$-algebra for measurability.

Comment: Measurable sets are closed under countable unions and countable intersections.

Answer (score 2):

**Explanation of the definition:**

We'd like to somehow describe the set of elements that appear in $E_n$ for infinitely many $n \in \Bbb N$.

Let's, however, start bigger.  What if we were to describe the elements that appear in some $E_k$ for all $k \geq 1$?  That would be the union of all $E_k$, or more simply
$$
A_1 = \bigcup_{k \geq 1} E_k
$$
What about the elements that appear in some $E_k$ for some $k \geq n$?  That would, by the same idea, be
$$
A_n = \bigcup_{k \geq n} E_k
$$
It should be clear that $A_1 \supseteq A_2 \supseteq \cdots \supseteq A_n \supseteq A_{n+1} \supseteq \cdots$.  Now, which elements appear in **every** $A_n$?  Well, if $x \in A_n$ for every $n$, then we must be able to say that for all $n$, there is a $k \geq n$ such that $x \in E_k$.  You should also be able to see that any element $x$ satisfying those conditions is an element of every $A_n$.

**Equivalently**, we could say that $x \in \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ if and only if $x \in E_n$ for infinitely many $n$.  That is, we can write the set of elements that appear in infinitely many $E_n$ as
$$
\limsup_{n \to \infty} E_n = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n = 
\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \left(\bigcup_{n\geq k} E_k\right)
$$
as the hint claims.

---

As for applying the hint: show that each $A_n$ is measurable.  By the nature of measurability, it follows that $\bigcap_{n = 1}^\infty A_n$, the countable intersection of measurable sets, is measurable.